# In ASP.NET Webforms, how do get my control to work in a link tag's href attribute?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

I have a situation where I need to dynamically load a URL prefix.

I wrote a quick control to handle this and it works for the following instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<gbn:AdminPath runat="server" id="Id1" />Rest/Of/Path.js'></script>
```

But the following case (on the same aspx page) does not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<gbn:AdminPath runat="server" id="Id2" />/css/styles.css'>
```

This shows up in the browser as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="&lt;gbn:AdminPath runat=&quot;server&quot; id=&quot;Id2&quot; />/css/styles.css" />
```

I've tried various things, but I can't seem to get the  tags working. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's going to work. I'm assuming that the control builds some kind of a path, but how will the href know which property or method holds the path?

Comment: It works on the <script> tag. The interesting thing is why it doesn't execute at all on the <link> tag.

Comment: That is interesting. What was the reasoning behind making it a user control? Wouldn't a static class method be easier?

Comment: I tried that as well... with the same results (see comment on TheGeekYouNeed's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that it treats `<link>` elements in the `<head>` section like they are server controls. It does this, I believe, so that you can use app-relative urls (eg "~/myfolder/file.css") and have them resolved for you. It does not give this same treatment to `<script>` tags, though.

Since they are treated as server controls, you cannot mix inline script and string literals in a property value or it all gets treated as a literal (as you discovered).

To get around this, you have several options, one of which TheGeekYouNeed outline above.

If you still want to do it inline with a public method, you can, but you have to build the whole property value in your code like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<%= string.Format("{0}/css/styles.css", GetAdminPath() %>' type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic explanation of why it behaves that way, and thanks for the very simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the  in the [code behind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

example:

```
// Define an HtmlLink control.
HtmlLink myHtmlLink = new HtmlLink();
myHtmlLink.Href = GetAdminPath() + "/pathtocss.css";
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
myHtmlLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

// Add the HtmlLink to the Head section of the page.
Page.Header.Controls.Add(myHtmlLink);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried creating a method in the code behind with the same results (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=GetAdminPath()%>/pathtocss.css">`) The "<" gets encoded without getting executed.

Comment: I suppose I could do that too. It just seems like I should just be able to write it into the markup with no issues.

Comment: You will need to use Page.ResolveUrl("~") to properly get the root directory, then, if you must do it in the markup.  Not sure why links for css files are such a pain.